# Problem With Understanding Joins and Their Workings

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]
I have a situation where I've got 5 different types of Exams.
20 Students Attempted and were graded for those exams.
now If I want to know the list of students who scored less the the average of particular exams.
How can I use joins to without using subqueries to get my result
if the Table I got has attributes, `'STUDENT_ID, EXAM_ID, SCORES'`.

In simple words, a query to retrieve student ID, exam ID and exam score of those students having
exam score less than the average score for that particular exam.

I've been trying to solve it, I'm unable to find any hints as to what I should do, as I keep getting problems, nearest to what I have gotten to is.

```
select y.exam_id,y.student_id,y.grades
from graded x join graded y on x.exam_id=y.exam_id AND x.grades               
(select avg(grades) from graded group by exam_id)
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you provide some sample data, table structure/schema of all the tables involved and your desired output.

Comment: Which is the reason you don't want to use subqueries?

Comment: I'm learning Join in depth, as far as I know , it's that all sub query problems can solved using joins. 
but another problem is I don't kind of getting any ideas about this even with subqueries.since I've got 5 different exams

Comment: @the_coding_cat I've added the table along with more info.

Comment: What is the basis for the average? You said *"having exam score less than the average score"* is not really clear to me

Comment: as far I understand , we need to calculate the average of all 5 different exams, than compare students who gave the particular exams to it's own respective exam average, and than we will do this for all exams to get all the students who were below average in their respective exams. But I'm not getting any ideas how to go further on it using sql

Comment: @the_coding_cat I think it is clear enough to provide an answer. Needs a list of records from graded_table where score is less than the average. IMHO

Comment: select g.*
from
 graded g
 inner join
 (
  select avg(scores) as exam_average
  from graded
  group by exam_id
 ) as subquery on g.scores < subquery.exam_average

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's no way to avoid subqueries, except maybe from mysql-specific constructs which I am not aware of.

Second, when using subqueries, I highly recommend using derived tables instead of oscurely using them as constants in various places.

Here:

```
select g.*
from
    graded g
    inner join
    (
        select avg(scores) as exam_average
        from graded
        group by exam_id
    ) as subquery on g.scores > subquery.exam_average
```